# website foobared in medium browser size and below (zurb foundation)

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

My website has some serious issues when you resize it to the medium and small views. It looks great at full screen and mobile view but has some serious issues in the browser when you shrink it down to medium and below. I've used foundation but also mixed in some non-foundation code that I think is causing some issues, such as the container. I also suspect there is something wrong with the top nav bar, because that looks off at shrunk views as well. There is a lot of code to look at but i will post some snippets here as well as link to the main site so you can look through the full code.

Here is some of the top bar and also I have a container which is not part of the grid which might be throwing things off, as well as a weird header element that I coded some css for and if removed throws it off as well. Basically, my code is a bit of a mess, and I will be cleaning it up best I can once I figure out what is causing a lot of this mess up when the browser is resized. (ps. to see the rest of the code and css, please visit www.omegadesignla.com and inspect element, or ask me to paste a specific part, thanks! )

```
 <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
          <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="name">

              <span><a href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="img/primarylogo.png"></a><span>
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
              <a href="#">Menu</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <section class="top-bar-section">

            <ul class="right">
              <li><a href="#about">About us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Contact us</a></li>

                <li class="has-dropdown">
                  <a href="#">Services</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="services.html#printing">Print Media</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Web Development</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Promotional Items</a></li>
                    <!-- <li class="active"><a href="#">Active link in dropdown</a></li> -->
                  </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </nav>    
  <div class="container">
    <header>

      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="large-3 medium-3 small-6 small-centered columns"> <!-- large centered -->
        <a id="topbutton" href="#" class="button large radius button">Take the tour!</a>

        </div>



      </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From debugging your site with firebug i see that the logo in the left top corner is a png with 720px width. Although you have class .logo width: 40% it makes the .title-area 720px width which breaks the layout.

try following additions to css:

```
.title-area { 
  max-width: 40%; //or whatever you need for your layout. px will work there, too
}
.title-area .logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

I'd also rewize the png to the needed size to save some kB to download.

I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the response, i I just tried it but no success. It still re-sizes flawed. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I added that code under the media query and it helped but when it gets down to under 700px it still messes up..

Comment: It's the logo image that makes the .title-area grow. If you resize the image to the right dimension it should work.

BTW: You can play around with the css in the browser using firebug. This helps a lot when debugging css

Comment: thanks for the tips, relly appriciate it. I will try to resize it great tip. Also, i use chrome inspector, is that ok instead of firebug?